# Запятая после "может" в вопросительных фразах

Tags: пунктуация, вводные-слова

Всё сходится к тому, что эти фразы не исключения и что вводное слово нужно отделять запятой, как например в вопросе: *Может, им сказать об этом?* Тем более, без запятой может быть смысл *"может им сказать кто-то ещё?",* то есть "может" как член предложения. Но уж больно меня смущает каждый раз то, что первые два слова произносятся очень активно, совершенно без пауз. То есть если немножко замешкаешься и сделаешь паузу между другими словами, то ничего, а если между первыми, то будет интонационно совсем плохо звучать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может, им сказАть об этом?

В устной речи предложение такой структуры произносится **без паузы**. Повышение тона, характерное для вопросительной интонации, делается, скорее всего, на слове "сказать" (но логически можно выделить и другие слова ("им" или "об этом").

**Пояснение**

Дело в том, что интонационные средства **являются ограниченными по своим возможностям,** и в этом случае сложно обозначить паузу,   а вот вопросительную интонацию обозначить необходимо. **Запятая ставится согласно только грамматическому принципу, без обозначения паузы.**

Грамматика предложения здесь **однозначно выражает содержание**, другой смысл возможен только при грамматической перестройке предложения.

Comment: Спасибо и за этот ответ! ;)